# Angular 6 build with --stats-json not generating stats.json file

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm trying to generate the stats.json file for my Angular 6 application. Below things I've already tried, but the file is not getting generated at all. My system requires to have **"npm run"** before every angular cli command.

1. I've ran **"npm run ng build --prod --stats-json"** as well as **"npm run ng build --prod --stats-json=true"**.
2. I've ran **"npm run ng build --stats-json"** as well as **"npm run ng build --stats-json=true"** (without the build command).
3. Used **"npm run ng build --statsJson=true"** by taking reference from cli documentation.

But still stats.json file is not being generated, which I want to read using webpack bundle analyzer.
Any help, suggestion or correction in this regard is welcome.

Below are the scripts in my package.json.

"scripts": {

```
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"gulp": "gulp",
"bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
"stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
```

},

Answer (score 16):

I found mine was in /dist.

This means if you look to git for changes appearing, it might be ignored.

Comment: ah this, ty. Underrated answer

Answer (score 5):

Check your package.json there should be a script section like below,

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

if it's then run

```
npm run build -- --statsJson=true
```

if your script is different please  post the script section from your packageJSon will update answer based on that

Comment: I've added the scripts above, please suggest.

Comment: The above command worked and I finally got the file. Thanks Ravin

Comment: For production build run this. npm run build -- --prod --statsJson=true

Comment: why no hyphen in `stats-json` as shown in the command `ng build --stats-json`. this used to work for me but isn't now with Angular 9

Comment: Hi @Simon_Weaver, I've found that the output json file name has been renamed to stats-es2015.json with Angular 9

Comment: I am using angular 10, I ran ng build --statsJson=true, and did not get any of these files.. any idea?

Comment: @danda I got the stats generated by runniung `ng build --statsJson=true` in Angular 10

Comment: --stats-json works for me. --statsJson=true gives me an unknown option error

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the argument `--statsJson=true` is not available in newer versions of the CLI or if it's because I'm using NX to build my app but anywway, here's how you can make it work:

- Open `angular.json` file
- In the JSON structure go to `projects` / `[YOUR-APP]` / `architect` / `build` / `configurations` / `production`
- Add a new key in this JSON object: `"statsJson": true`

Launch your build **and don't forget to launch it with the correct environment**. In this case `production` so I need to pass the `--prod` argument when building the app otherwise it'll pick another configuration which doesn't have the new flag `"statsJson": true`!

Answer (score 2):

When I ran this command:

```
npm run build --stats-json,
```

It generated one file called:

```
stats-es2015.json
```

Then, everything was ok, when I ran:

```
npm run webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/PROJECT_NAME/stats-es2015.json
```

My environment was:

```
"@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check out my simple workaround that can be used to create manifest and read its content by i.e. Node.js app.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-manifest